# mysql count(*) left join group by - the number of files in a folder

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `fileid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `filesize` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `folder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fileid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `folders` (
  `directoryid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `directoryname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`directoryid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How to get a list of all folders and the number of files they hold, including folders who have no (zero) files? Recursion must not be taken into account.

Found it

```
select folders.directoryid, folders.directoryname, count(files.fileid) as no_files
from  folders
left join files on files.folder = folders.directoryid
group by folders.directoryid, folders.directoryname
```

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select folders.directoryname, 
       count(files.fileid) 
from folders left outer join 
     files on folders.directoryid = files.folder 
group by folders.directoryid
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
SELECT f.directoryid,
   COUNT(fs.fileid) CountOfFiles
FROM folders f LEFT JOIN
    files fs ON f.DirectoryID = fs.folder
GROUP BY f.directoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT directoryname, COUNT(files.fileid) AS filecount
FROM folders
LEFT JOIN files ON files.folder = folders.directoryid
GROUP BY directoryid
ORDER BY directoryname
```